# Get error flag/message from a queued process in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, error-handling, multiprocessing, queue

I am preparing a Python multiprocessing tool where I use `Process` and `Queue` commands. The queue is putting another script in a process to run in parallel. As a sanity check, in the queue, I want to check if there is any error happing in my other script and return a flag/message if there was an error (`status = os.system()` will run the process and `status` is a flag for error). But I can't output errors from the queue/child in the `consumer` process to the parent process. Following are the main parts of my code (shortened):

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock

command_queue = Queue()
lock = Lock()

p = Process(target=producer, args=(command_queue, lock, test_config_list_path))
for i in range(consumer_num):
    c = Process(target=consumer, args=(command_queue, lock))
    consumers.append(c)

p.daemon = True
p.start()

for c in consumers:
    c.daemon = True
    c.start()

p.join()
for c in consumers:
    c.join()

if error_flag:
    Stop_this_process_and_send_a_message!



def producer(queue, lock, ...):
    for config_path in test_config_list_path:
        queue.put((config_path, process_to_be_queued))



def consumer(queue, lock):
    while True:
        elem = queue.get()
        if elem is None:
            return
        status = os.system(elem[1])
        if status:
            error_flag = 1
    time.sleep(3)
```

Now I want to get that `error_flag` and use it in the main code to handle things. But seems I can't output `error_flag` from the `consumer` (child) part to the main part of the code. I'd appreciate it if someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your update, I also pass an `multiprocessing.Event` instance to your `to_do` process. This allows you to simply issue a call to `wait` on the event in the main process, which will block until a call to `set` is called on it. Naturally, when `to_do` or one of its threads detects a script error, it would call `set` on the event after setting `error_flag.value` to `True`. This will wake up the main process who can then call method `terminate` on the process, which will do what you want. On a normal completion of `to_do`, it still is necessary to call `set` on the event since the main process is blocking until the event has been set. But in this case the main process will just call `join` on the process.

Using a `multiprocessing.Value` instance alone would have required periodically checking its value in a loop, so I think waiting on a `multiprocessing.Event` is better. I have also made a couple of other updates to your code with comments, so please review them:

```py
import multiprocessing
from ctypes import c_bool
...

def to_do(event, error_flag):
    # Run the tests
    wrapper_threads.main(event, error_flag)
    # on error or normal process completion:
    event.set()

def git_pull_change(path_to_repo):

    repo = Repo(path)
    current = repo.head.commit

    repo.remotes.origin.pull()
    if current == repo.head.commit:
        print("Repo not changed. Sleep mode activated.")
        # Call to time.sleep(some_number_of_seconds) should go here, right?
        return False
    else:
        print("Repo changed. Start running the tests!")
        return True

def main():
    while True:
        status = git_pull_change(git_path)
        if status:
            # The repo was just pulled, so no point in doing it again:
            #repo = Repo(git_path)
            #repo.remotes.origin.pull()
            event = multiprocessing.Event()
            error_flag = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, False, lock=False)
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=to_do, args=(event, error_flag))
            process.start()
            # wait for an error or normal process completion:
            event.wait()
            if error_flag.value:
                print('Error! breaking the process!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                process.terminate() # Kill the process
            else:
                process.join()
            break
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used your initial suggestion, just brought it a few levels up and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should *always* tag multiprocessing questions with the platform you are running on. Since I do not see your process-creating code within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, I have to assume you are running on a platform that uses OS `fork` calls to create new processes, such as Linux.

That means your newly created processes inherit the value of `error_flag` when they are created but for all intents and purposes, if a process modifies this variable, it is modifying a local copy of this variable that exists in an address space that is unique to that process.

You need to create `error_flag` in shared memory and pass it as an argument to your process:

```py
from multiprocessing import Value
from ctypes import c_bool
...
error_flag = Value(c_bool, False, lock=False)
for i in range(consumer_num):
    c = Process(target=consumer, args=(command_queue, lock, error_flag))
    consumers.append(c)
...

if error_flag.value:
    ...
    #Stop_this_process_and_send_a_message!




def consumer(queue, lock, error_flag):
    while True:
        elem = queue.get()
        if elem is None:
            return
        status = os.system(elem[1])
        if status:
            error_flag.value = True
    time.sleep(3)
```

But I have a questions/comments for you. You have in your original code the following statement:

```py
if error_flag:
    Stop_this_process_and_send_a_message!
```

But this statement is located *after* you have already joined all the started processes. So what processes are there to stop and where are you sending a message to (you have potentially multiple consumers any of which might be setting the `error_flag` -- by the way, no need to have this done under a lock since setting the value `True` is an atomic action). And since you are joining all your processes, i.e. waiting for them to complete, I am not sure why you are making them daemon processes. You are also passing a `Lock` instance to your producer and consumers, but it is not being used at all.

Your consumers return when they get a `None` record from the queue. So if you have N consumers, the last N elements of `test_config_path` need to be `None`.

I also see no need for having the `producer` process. The main process could just as well write all the records to the queue either before or even after it starts the consumer processes.

The call to `time.sleep(3)` you have at the end of function `consumer` is unreachable.

Comment: Thanks Booboo, this is very helpful to understand how to handle this arg. However, I have a nested multiprocess process in my toolbox. One process is checking a variable online and if the variable is changed, it triggers another process in parallel, which that process itself is running a separate multiprocess to do some tests in parallel. Let me give you a summary/flowchart of my toolbox. Here has a character limitation, so I will post it as an answer.

Comment: I just posted the complete issue I have.

Answer (score 0):

So the above code summary is the inner process to run some tests in parallel. I removed the def function part from it, but just assume that is the `wrapper_threads` in the following code summary. Here I'll add the parent process which is checking a variable (let's assume a commit in my git repo). The following process is meant to run indefinitely and when there is a change it will trigger the multiprocess in the main question:

```
def to_do():
    # Run the tests
    wrapper_threads.main()


def git_pull_change(path_to_repo):

    repo = Repo(path)
    current = repo.head.commit

    repo.remotes.origin.pull()
    if current == repo.head.commit:
        print("Repo not changed. Sleep mode activated.")
        return False
    else:
        print("Repo changed. Start running the tests!")
        return True

def main():
    process = None
    while True:
        status = git_pull_change(git_path)

    if status:
        repo = Repo(git_path)
        repo.remotes.origin.pull()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=to_do)
        process.start()

    if error_flag.value:
        print('Error! breaking the process!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        os.system('pkill -U user XXX')
        break
```

Now I want to propagate that `error_flag` from the child process to this process and stop process `XXX`. The problem is that I don't know how to bring that `error_flag` to this (grand)parent process.

Comment: First, is your indentation off? In function `main` you will execute `status = git_pull_change(git_path)` repeatedly in a loop and never fall through to testing `status`.  So the logic is not that clear as to whether you might even starting multiple `processes` or not because you will be continually checking if `git pull` results in a change or once you start `to_do` process you will wait until an error. It seems like your intention is to start multiple processes, but I want to make sure. Update your question with corrections and clarifications and post a comment to me when you have done so.

Comment: I guess you can't be re-pulling the repository while you are in the middle or running tests so it would have to be just a single run of tests.